# some error while running spring mvc maven project

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, spring-mvc

When I run my project I always produce the error in console. But I can run the project. Please help me to find the reason.

```
Jul 09, 2015 1:48:04 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig processAnnotationsJar
SEVERE: Unable to process Jar entry [com/google/common/collect/EnumMultiset.class] from Jar [jar:file:/home/cinesoft/WORKSPACES/workspaceathira/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/CinehomeUpdate/WEB-INF/lib/guava-12.0.1.jar!/] for annotations
java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid LOC header (bad signature)
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.read(Native Method)
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.access$1400(ZipFile.java:56)
at java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInputStream.read(ZipFile.java:679)
at java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInflaterInputStream.fill(ZipFile.java:415)
at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(InflaterInputStream.java:158)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:235)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:254)
at java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(DataInputStream.java:387)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ClassParser.readID(ClassParser.java:237)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ClassParser.parse(ClassParser.java:114)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsStream(ContextConfig.java:2147)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsJar(ContextConfig.java:2023)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsUrl(ContextConfig.java:1989)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotations(ContextConfig.java:1974)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1321)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:880)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:378)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5343)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Corrupted jar may be.

Answer (score 0):

This is because, your jars are probably corrupted.

Please clear your repository `~/.m2/repository` and after that force an update for maven build as

```
mvn -U clean package
```

And plrease try again.